# trace for HttpModule calls

Tags: iis, httpmodule

I'm developing an HttpModule. Some of its events are not called and I think it's because other HttpModules that are installed are ending the request or something similar.

Is it possible to configure IIS to produce a log of all the HttpModule requests in their order?

e.g.:

HttpModule1 BeginRequest called.

HttpModule2 BeginRequest called.

So I would know which methods are called on each HttpModule? (and try to identify why & where the request is ended)

**NOTE:** I don't control all the modules, so I can't just add logging in all of them...